# Strange NullReferenceException in Unity Script (C#)

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, unity-game-engine

The Project works fine, until a certain point is reached, then suddenly it starts throwing NRE's. 
Here's some source code :

```
void Start(){
myhealth = GetComponentInChildren<HealthBar>();
    if(myhealth == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("myhealth is null !!"); //It never outputs something here
    }
}

//And Here it works :
public void ApplyDamage(float amount)
{
    myhealth.DamageEnemy(amount);
    if (GetHealth() <= 0)
    { 
       [...]
    }
}

//Then suddenly it throws NRE's here when accesing it from another Script :
 public void AddHealth(float a)
{
    myhealth.HealEnemy(a); //Here
}

public float GetHealth()
{
     return myhealth.GetHealth(); //And here
}
```

In the HealthBar script there are these variables and these functions:

```
public float maxHealth;
public float currentHealth;
private float originalScale;

public void DamageEnemy(float giveDamage)
{
    currentHealth -= giveDamage;
}

public void HealEnemy(float heal)
{
    currentHealth += heal;
}

public float GetHealth()
{
    return currentHealth;
}
```

There doesn't seem to be a reason for the Script to be throwing NRE's, but it still does.

Comment: Is all the code in the fist block on the same script?

Comment: yes it is. the 2nd block is another script

Comment: Where do you declare the variable _myhealth_? Are you using the same instance of the first class when you receive the NRE? Your code above misses some context. In particular the code that calls Start, ApplyDamage and AddHealth

Comment: a Unity Script (MonoDevelop) Calls the Start() function right when the Object begins to be ingame 
-> the myhealth variable is always the same from the Start() on and never gets changed

Comment: Post your `HealthBar` script

Comment: the HealthBar script is in the lower box ?

Comment: Who calls AddHealth/GetHealth and ApplyDamage? Do you have a collection of the top script that simply runs through and calls all items? You could be killing an enemy but the collection keeps the reference and runs the AddHealth on dead object.

Answer (score 1):

Just like you did in your `Start()` function, try adding

```
if(myhealth == null)
{
    Debug.Log("myhealth is null !!");
}
```

into your

```
public void AddHealth(float a)
{
    myhealth.HealEnemy(a);
}
```

leading to

```
public void AddHealth(float a)
{
    if(myhealth == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("myhealth is null !!");
    }
    else
        myhealth.HealEnemy(a);
}
```

The `myhealth` is obtained in the `Start()` using the `myhealth = GetComponentInChildren<HealthBar>();` Which by itself is fine.

*But* what happens when the child object you got this component from gets destroyed, removed, or deactivated? You might have guessed it, the component no longer exists either.